# What is this plant with purple bellflowers on a spike?

Tags: identification

Could someone identify this flowering plant?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *Delphinium*; it has flowered whilst still very short. These usually reach a height of somewhere between 4-7 feet, depending on variety. You don't say how long the plant has been in situ nor where you are in the world, but the foliage is still growing upwards, and may yet reach a more normal height and produce more flowers. These plants are herbaceous perennials, meaning they die down in winter and reappear in spring the following year. They are usually  planted at  the back of a flower bed or border because of their height, and prefer rich, fertile, relatively moist (but not waterlogged) soil that does not completely dry out frequently; they are prone to slug and snail damage early in spring as they start into growth. Image here https://www.premierseedsdirect.com/product/delphinium-pacific-giant-blue-bird/

Comment: Thanks for answering. I would say it was planted only a few months ago, at the _front_ of a public flower bed. I look forward to seeing how tall they can grow.